# I don't get a merge commit with GIT and keep having conflicts

Tags: git, merge

We're having trouble with merging with `GIT`. We created a feature branch from `origin/master` and are now trying to update the feature branch with the latest changes from `origin/master`.

I expect (and want) this merge to result in a merge commit. It doesn't. Why and how can we fix this?

The merge results in a number of conflicts. When all conflicts were fixed, I expected to see a merge commit (commit with two parent commits). No such luck.

I also expected a single commit which contains the conflict resolutions. However, there are a lot of commits added to the history. It looks more like a rebase than a merge. How is this possible?

I want later merges to have a merge base that won't cause conflicts that we've already seen earlier. So we tried to merge again from `origin/master`, hoping to get an actual merge commit this time. Again no such luck.

We're still getting merge conflicts and after resolving those there is still no merge commit. I fear we have to keep fixing the same issues indefinitely. That's not want I want (I know of `rerere`). I want the repository to reflect that we did a merge.

How can resolving conflicts from a `git merge origin/master` end up in multiple commits looking like a `rebase` result? I feel that if that didn't happen, I would not have further issues.

For the record, our team uses the `Gerrit` code-review tool. This causes us to have quite a lot of (small) merge commits in our repository as changes are typically not fully `rebased` when reviewed and merged. I feel this info shouldn't be relevant, but just to be sure.

Comment: Did you add and commit the files with the conflicts after you had resolved the merge commits?

Comment: We used "git mergetool". After resolution, the files were automatically added to the staging area. We did the "git commit" when there were no more changes. We have ui.color set to true. Everything was green before the commit, nothing was red.

Comment: Its not possible for me to visualize what kind of commit -history you have. If you are open to it, can you paste the output of `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` till some commits in your question?

Comment: I can do that but it results in 396 lines (out of a total of 10000). Should I use something like www.wetransfer.com? Or copy/paste in a new answer to this question?

Comment: Yeah, just share it via a service - like pastebin or as a gist and add the link to your question.

Comment: Please take a look at http://pastebin.com/ppszv6rz. As this is a closed source project, I had to remove quite some text but that shouldn't matter for this discussion. I've annotated the branches relate to the merge. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. git merge --squash will always result in a non-merge commit (with only a single parent commit). The reason why we specified this was because if we didn't and we pushed the merge commit to our Gerrit server, we got A LOT of new changes in Gerrit which need manual review and approval. I'm not yet entirely sure why this is not always the case but Gerrit created new reviews for all the commits that were already in the repository but we now added to the branch's history... Colleagues thought that these reviews were actual new commits. That isn't the case. They were the same changesets, but now listed under a new branch.

The problems is now that we require to manually approve every commit that has become part of the merge target branch's history. But that's for a different stackoverflow question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the problem
stay in the feature branch. install meld or do the git merging with master branch.
do a

```
git fetch.
```

(`git merge origin/master`) (Think you already completed this).
after fixing conflicts check

```
git status
```

if you have changes there then add all the files and do a commit. then push it to the remote.

do a git fetch again

after that try go into master branch and merge master with that feature